# Reading int from ifstream to 2-D dynamic array

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to programming and am trying to read an array of ints  into a 2-D dynamic array. I'm relatively sure this is just a syntax issue.

The array is dynamic and therefore is of type int**. To try to populate the  array, I've used a nested for loop to populate each element of the array with  the next term from the ifstream. Input is assumed to be all ints separated by
whitespace.

```
//declare dynamic 2-D array
int** myArray = new int*[numRows]
for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
{
    myArray[i] = new int[numCols];
}

//populate array from ifstream
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++)
    {
        inFile >> myArray[i][j];
    }
}
```

I expected to be able to store the ints from the ifstream (all between 0-100)  directly into the array, but I seem to be storing addresses instead (very 
 large negative ints). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A typo-ish bug: `for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)` Otherwise you'll probably have the wrong number of rows in the array, leading to much gnashing of teeth later

Comment: Side note: [There is a much better way to do this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op). Arrays of arrays can be painfully slow due to all the hopping around the CPU has do do chasing pointers. If you can keep all of your storage together in one big block a modern CPU can easily load up the cache ahead of time and ZOOOOOOM! Plus you have less memory management to deal with.

Comment: Well not that it is a panacea either -- `"Put it this way: the operator() approach is never worse than, and sometimes better than, the [][] approach:"` Not a direct correlation to *Arrays of arrays can be painfully slow due to all the hopping around the CPU has do do chasing pointers.* If as in this case all pointers are allocated in a single allocation, e.g. `int** myArray = new int*[numRows]` the pointers themselves, while not guaranteed, are sequential in memory, and in like fashion, so is each row allocated. The only indirection being reading where each row resides from the pointers.

Comment: @user4581301 -- but your point is well-taken.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the typo and a missing semicolon should fix it

```
// declare dynamic 2-D array
int** myArray = new int*[numRows]
//                               ^
//                               ;
for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
  //                ^^^^^^^
  //                numRows
  myArray[i] = new int[numCols];
}
```